# Is is possible to install dependancies with single line command?

Tags: node.js, npm

My Node.js

```
package.json
```

has following dependancies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.10",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0"
  },
```

I am new to JS,so I want to know if we can somehow invoke package.json without going for

```
npm install
```

for every package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the command `npm install` or `npm i`, it will install all dependencies from your package.json.

> As a result you get all the dependencies listed in the package.json from the current folder

You can see the documentation concerning this command here : [npm install](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/installing-and-removing-external-software-using-node-package-manager.html#ws_npm_command_line_installation)

Comment: Ok,it works. If node_modules are already in directory I should delete them?

Comment: You can if you want to restart from a clean `node_modules`, but it will work without deleting it

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to JS world, I'm fairly new to JS myself but I believe there two possible solutions to your problem:

### `npm install` multiple dependencies

It is possible to install multiple dependencies at the same time with one `npm install` command, you may find more information that could be helpful in the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

For example:

```sh
npm install got koa fs-extra
```

Here I have installed all 3 of my project dependencies at once.

### Pre Populate `package.json`

You can manually add the package dependencies in the correct format to your `package.json` file. You might the npm [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) on the `package.json` file helpful.

You then will need to run:

```sh
npm install
```

This will take the dependencies in the `package.json` file and install them into the `node_modules/` directory.